# jQuery alternatate rows color - IE problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Why is it that this code:

```
$('#tbl tr:odd').css('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
$('#tbl tr:even').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
```

[works fine](http://jsbin.com/arima) outside of the plugin in all browsers. While the same code:

```
$('tr:odd', $this).css('background-color', options.tr_odd_bgcolor);
$('tr:even', $this).css('background-color', options.tr_even_bgcolor);
```

doesn't color rows at all in any version of IE where `$this` refers to table specified in wrapped set and `options.tr_odd_bgcolor` refers to color for example `green`.

The plugin styling does apply in all browsers except for IE.

Here is the plugin code for your reference:

```
    (function($){
        $.fn.styleTable = function(settings){
            var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.styleTable.defaults, settings);

            return this.each(function(settings){
               var options = $.extend({}, opts, $(this).data());
               var $this = $(this);

           $('tr:odd', $this).css('background-color', options.tr_odd_bgcolor);
           $('tr:even', $this).css('background-color', options.tr_even_bgcolor);
            });
        }

      $.fn.styleTable.defaults = {
        tr_odd_bgcolor: '#f6f6f6',
        tr_even_bgcolor: '#fff'
      }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$this` is valid. You should be using either `$(this)` which takes the current DOM element in context and turns it into a jQuery object, or `this`, which is the standard Javascript way to access the current object instance in whose context you are executing. `$this` isn't valid Javascript at all. Did you perhaps make a typo in your question?

Comment: @Marc W: Nope, tried that that isn't the issue, also $this is equalized to $(this) in plugin code.

Comment: `$variable` is actually a common practice, to denote you're dealing with a jQuery object.

Comment: var $this = $(this); This line selects element in context, turn it into a jquery object and store it in memory.

Comment: @Marc W, @Nick Craver: You guys can try the plugin code for yourself. I really need to sort this out, i think this is a bug in jquery probably.

Comment: @user429381 - I setup a test page here, working in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eHtjQ/

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? your codes work for me in ie6-8. Have you tried $this.find(selector) ?

Comment: @Nick Craver: Well yes there is something wrong in my code which is beside what i have posted above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the plugin.  Without debugging I just rewrote the plugin using another as a base and it works fine in IE8 now.

http://jsbin.com/oxaxi3

Odd that when you click "preview" in jsbin it doesn't seem to work, but when you just view the base url as I pasted above it works fine.